# Assigning a String value to a row

Tags: c, arrays, character

I'm thinking how can I assign a string value to a row in a 2*2 character array in C?
this can be done in java like this:

```
    char [][] array = new char[10][10];
    array[1] = "foo".toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, you can't "assign" to an array. You can, however, **copy** a string literal (or any string) into the array. You just need to make sure that you don't cause buffer overflows:

```
char arr[10][10];

const char *str = "foo";
if (strlen(str) < sizeof(arr[1])) {
    strcpy(arr[1], str);
}
```

Alternatively, you can assign to a pointer (which is a member of an array of pointers):

```
const char *arr[10];
arr[1] = "foo";
```

One can't really tell which one you need to use unless you provide more context as to what you want to use the array for.

Comment: My upvote to this answer is just because you pointed memory leak to my answer.